# IntelliJ scala project import

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I have a scala project in IntelliJ with a simple folder structure
 `src/core/CommonCSVReader.scala`
I have a `program.scala` file under `src/`
i run spark-shell from the integrated terminal, and try to run `:load program.scala`
i get the following error:

> object CommonCSVReader is not a member of package core

even is i exit spark-shell and try to run `scala program.scala` i get the same problem, I wanted to try running the `program.scala` from intelliJ but if I right click on program.scala I don't have the Run ScalaApp option, only Run Scala console which just starts a Scala console, I can't find what I'm missing here, thank you,

program.scala

```
import core.CommonCSVReader

object program {
 def main():Unit = {
 val path:String = "some/path"

val reader = new CommonCSVReader(path)
reader.Read()
}
}
```

EDIT:
please find CommonCSVReader Class below:

```
package core

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

class CommonCSVReader(filename:String) extends ParserFileReader(filename) {
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.master", 
"local").getOrCreate()
 def Read():Unit = {
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", 
"true").csv(filename)

   //Show Schema
    df.printSchema()
  }
 }
```

Comment: can we see the directory structure of your project?

Comment: parser/src/core/CommonCSVReader. scala

parser/src/program. scala

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
package core
```

to the beginning of `CommonCSVReader.scala`.
Just putting it inside the folder isn't enough.

Edit:

I also just noticed, that you didn't put your packages inside a scala folder.
The "usual" path is:

```
src/main/scala/<packages>
```

Though I am not sure if this has an affect or not

Comment: I edited my question please find CommonCSVReader.scala code, I already declared the package in the header, and I also tried to change the folder structure to `src/main/scala/core` but with no success

Comment: There are two things that might be the problem. First: scala-folder needs to be declared source-root. Second: maybe you didn't add the sdk yet

Comment: no these were not my problem and sure I have scala sdk, please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

`program.scala`

```
import core.CommonCSVReader

object program extends App {
val path:String = "some/path"

val reader = new CommonCSVReader(path)
reader.Read()
}
```

it seems I have to extends App, now when I right click on `program.scala` I have the option `run 'program'` and it works fine, but not from the terminal